# Using Scala class in Java test with Gradle

Tags: java, scala, gradle, build.gradle

I have a project with the following files:

```
src/main/scala/package/Class.scala
src/test/java/package/ClassTest.java
```

When I run `./gradlew clean build test` I get an error in :compileTestJava - it says "error: cannot find symbol" because apparently ClassTest.java cannot find Class.scala

I have the following in build.gradle which I think should work but doesn't:

```
sourceSets {
    test {
        java { srcDirs += ['src/main/scala', 'src/test/java'] }
    }
}
```

I also have the following plugins for what it is worth:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'scala'
    id 'java-library'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'jacoco'
}
```

The only other things in build.gradle are repositories and dependencies

Comment: Just out of curiosity why writing tests with **Java**? Usually what happens is the opposite a **Java** project with tests written with **Scala**.

Comment: I am writing a .jar file and making sure that classes work as expected in Java.

Comment: Calling **Scala** code from **Java** isn't as straight forward as calling **Java** from **Scala**. A common advice I have seen is to write an interface in **Java** and implement it in **Scala**, to simplify the Interop.

Comment: That is why I am writing tests.

Answer (score 0):

I have simulated your scenario locally.   The below works with Gradle 6.5 and 'java' and 'scala' plugins.   My main srcDirs are slightly different from yours but I do not think that is material.

**build.gradle:**

```
sourceSets
{
    main
            {
        scala {
            srcDirs = ['app/glue', 'app/controllers', 'app/models']
        }
    }

    test {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['test/java']
        }
        scala {
            srcDirs = ['test/scala']
        }
    }
}
```

**Sample JUnit test** which refers to a scala case class `Form` which is defined in the 'main' source set:

```
public class TestScalaFromJava
{
    @Test
    public void testNothing() { }

    @Test
    public void testScalaClassInJava1() {
        Firm firm = new Firm(1, "hello", "mello", "yellow");
    }
}
```

I can then run either of the below and they work:

- `./gradlew compileTestJava`
- `./gradlew clean build test`

Comment: I am not using that new a version of Gradle I think but I have been meaning to revisit this as I think Gradle 6.1 now gives control over which order different languages are compiled in.